# How to return a string from child form to main form (not open any new form)?

Tags: c#, constructor

My problem is:
Main form is opened first, there is a button to open Child form. I use Constructor and I want return a string from Child form to the textbox on Main form, and my code now is:

```
 Form1 f = new Form1(txt1.Text);
 f.Show();
```

But, a new main form will open up, the string won't fill in the first main form.
So how to work with only one main form?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, I'm not sure what you're trying to do. What exactly should happen when you click the button, and when should the string be filled in on the main form?

Comment: Sorry I am still confused. You say you want to have 2 forms, but then you don't want a form to open? Those seem to be opposite things. Sorry but I just can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Because Form1 is already opened, i want add a string from Form2 direct to that Form1, not open a new form and add the string to it

Comment: Add a public property to your Form2 class so the code in Form1 can read it.  And then you need to know exactly when it is a good time to read it, fall in the pit of success by displaying Form2 with its ShowDialog() method.  You can get more fancy when you start to understand Winforms programming better, later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, get it via OpenForms:

```
Form1 frm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Make sure you declare your control txt1 as public on its Modifier property so that you can access it from Child form:

```
        Form1 frm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().FirstOrDefault();
        frm.txt1.Text = "Change";
        frm.Show();
```

Now if you are trying to change it via its constructor, I doubt you can do it since it was already initialize, unless you call another new Form1 to initialize it and will go through its constructor again.

What you can do is change its property directly:

```
        Form1 frm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().FirstOrDefault();
        frm.stringMain = "Foo";  //Your property you want to change
        frm.txt1.Text = "Change";
        frm.Show();
```

Comment: Still don't understand your codes. I have set properties of the label in Form1 from private to public, so now I can have this: 
**`  frm.mylabel.Text = MyString;  `**

Comment: Yes exactly. What is the error you are experiencing? @Nlive

Comment: You really want to pass the value via constructor? Then you cannot access it on Form1 since its already open unless you want to open a new Form1? Let me know so that I can edit my code. @Nlive

Comment: Yeah, i has string  **` y`** on Form2, and i want show it on MyLabel.txt in Form1.  But I dont want open a new Form1 and change Mylabel's properties. Why i can perform a linebreak...

Comment: Because its already open. So it will not go through the constructor. That's how it works. Once you launch the Form1, it will go through the constructor one time only. And it will never go through again, unless you open a new instance of Form1. @Nlive

Comment: Thanks for your devoted help. So I keep this line **`public System.Windows.Forms.Label lb1;`** for my homework.